# Embedding html into PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the below code

```
$Query='SELECT * FROM  `courses`';
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$Query);
echo'<select name="courses" multiple>';
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ echo"<option value=\"";$data['title'];echo"\">";$data['title'];echo'</option>';}
echo"</select>";
```

I am trying to return values from a table,Database into a Multiple Selection menu. but it keeps giving me the below error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\wamp\www\ETT Logo\Controlpanel\addteacher.php on line 51

Please note that Line 51 is the line inside of the 'while' brackets.

Will Appreciate any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you can not make echo option in right way.
Try below code it's works for you

```
$Query='SELECT * FROM  `courses`';
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$Query);
echo'<select name="courses[]" multiple>';
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     echo "<option value='".$data['title']."'>".$data['title']."</option>";
}
echo"</select>";
```

Comment: name="courses" will hold multiple selected value in it ??

Comment: I update code try now

Comment: This one worked. thanks alot. I appreciate it.

Comment: may I ask, what's with the dots you added? it seems like the dots did the job..

Comment: Dot means it join your string..dot use to CONCAT string.

Comment: For more detail see below link http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
     echo "<option value='{$data['title']}'>{$data['title']}</option>";
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work. thanks for the help though

Comment: Now it is proper code. Maybe you have another error now?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it's a lot easier to understand:

```
$title = $data['title'];
echo "<option value='{$title}'>{$title}</option>";
```

Comment: Tried this one, didnt work, still gave me the same error.

Comment: please take note of the use of single quote and double quote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo'<select name="courses[]" multiple>';    
// to hold multiple selected values name must be an array

while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    echo '<option value="'. $data['title'] .'">'. $data['title'] .'</option>';
}
echo'</select>';
```

Answer (score -2):

you need to use '.' for this one...

```
echo"<option value=' .$data[title]. '>;
```